# Construct piece-wise linear mixed effect models

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, nonparametric, splines

I'm looking at the BMACS dataset(data(BMACS)), and is trying to construct a local constant fit without covariates using base functions B1(t) = 1 for t < 2, B2(t) = 1 for 2 <=t <4 and B3(t) = 1 for 4<=t with random effects for each of the base function. Two interior knots are chosen at t=2,4.

Since we are not considering covariates, the models will have simple piece-wise linear mixed effects that estimate post infection of CD4 as a function of time.

I do not know how to break slope into different pieces or sections for estimations, and since basis functions are equal to 1 then we would be only interested in the intercept. To extract spline estimates that is the only approach I can think of as for now:

```
 t <- BMACS$Time
 Tgrid <- seq(from=T.range[1], to=T.range[2], length=N)
 BS <- bs(Tgrid, knots=c(2,4), degree=2, intercept=T)
 mean.hat <- BS %*% fixef(fmCD4)
```

I'm trying to make a plot that shows time vs. estimates for this piece-wise mixed model effects for each section, but I can't figure out a way to include random-effects for each of the basis functions.

Following is how I planned to set up the model with random effect:

```
bs.time <- bs(BMACS$Time, knots=c(2,4), degree=2, intercept=T)
fmCD4 <- lmer(CD4 ~ 0+bs.time+(1+bs.time|ID), data=BMACS)
```

Any suggestions and guidance will be appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

You can directly include the call to `bs()` into the formula argument of `lmer()`, e.g.,

```
fm <- lmer(CD4 ~ bs(Time, knots = c(2,4), degree = 1) + 
             (bs(Time, knots = c(2,4), degree = 1) | ID), 
           data = BMACS)
```

Note that `degree` needs to be set to 1 to correspond to a piecewise-linear model.

Comment: Will this allow me to break the slope for different sections of time? Such as B1(t) = 1 for t < 2, B2(t) = 1 for 2 <=t <4 and B3(t) = 1 for 4<=t

Comment: The fit is equivalent, but the coefficients you obtain from `bs()` will not correspond to the slopes in the different intervals.